# Cannot run an instance of a docker image on azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I have created a simple asp.net core web application using visual studio templates. I have then created a docker file  which looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]
```

I have then built an image out of this using:

```
docker build -t webapplication:dev .
```

and then created and run a container from this using:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp webapplication:dev
```

This all works locally. I have then tried pushing this out to azure container registry and its been pushed successfully. However when I try to run an instance of this container, I get an error in Azure saying "The supported Windows versions are: '10.0.14393,10.0.17763'"

I don't understand why I am getting this error? The image works locally (I can check by browsing to localhost:8080 and checking that I get a valid response back, which I do). Is this something to do with ACR? What is the workaround? Is this something to do with the version of my windows (I am on 10.0.18363 Build 18363) Is my system too new for this to work which seems unlikely? Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows containers, the version of the OS on the host should match the version of the OS on the container. You should choose an appropriate base image to make your container being able to run on Azure.
https://samcogan.com/windows-containers-and-azure states:

> **OS Version**
>
> Due to limitations in how Windows implements the container run time, you require that the host machine is running the same version of Windows as in your container. I don't just mean the same family, but the same version. So if your host is running Server 2016 v1803, then your containers also need to run Server 2016 v1803, they cannot be running v1709. This is very problematic as it means rebuilding your images any time your host OS changes. It's even more problematic for those trying to use cloud providers, as often you won't know what OS is running on the machines you are hosted on.
>   You can combat this issue by running your containers as HyperV containers, which wraps your container in a thin virtual machine to abstract it from the OS, but this adds complexity.